# How to solve ERROR: Failed to parse XML in AndroidManifest.xml in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried several things like removing tags,adding taga,etc but still I am getting this error in my AndroidManifest.xml file

ERROR: Failed to parse XML in E:\flutter_Apps\flutter_app_dont_stare_v2\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
ParseError at [row,col]:[23,35]
Message: expected start or end tag
Affected Modules: app

[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOwQp.png)

**<<<<<---------EDIT------------------>>>>>>>**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.flutterappdontstarev2"
    tools:ignore="ExtraText">
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application tools:ignore="ExtraText">
        android:name=".Application"
        android:label="Stare Away"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="wxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx1" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />

        <service
            android:name="io.flutter.plugins.androidalarmmanager.AlarmService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />

        <receiver
            android:name="io.flutter.plugins.androidalarmmanager.AlarmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false" />
        <receiver
            android:name="io.flutter.plugins.androidalarmmanager.RebootBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" />


    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Post Your `AndroidManifest.xml` code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `>` at the end of line 20.
Also change the `/>` at the end of line line 25 to `>`

So the Xml can be valid

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.flutterappdontstarev2"
    tools:ignore="ExtraText">
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

    <application
        tools:ignore="ExtraText"
        android:name=".Application"
        android:label="Stare Away"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"


        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />

        <service
            android:name="io.flutter.plugins.androidalarmmanager.AlarmService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />

        <receiver
            android:name="io.flutter.plugins.androidalarmmanager.AlarmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false" />
        <receiver
            android:name="io.flutter.plugins.androidalarmmanager.RebootBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: @ JideGuru I have included that in the edits.Thanks for the help man